# How To Create Saved Search to Get Files from InventoryItems

Tags: netsuite

I have a PHP script on my website that uses PHPToolkit to connect via SOAP to my client's NetSuite environment.

They have datasheets associated with their InventoryItems in the Communication tab under Activities.

I need to download the files and serve them from the website.

I found SOAP does not expose the Files, and I am told that I need to use a Saved Search.

However, I am unable to determine how to create a Saved Search that will get me Files for InventoryItems.

The documentation says file attachments are available for certain types of search, but does not list InventoryItems. I do see Activities. But when I try to create a Saved Search on Activities I cannot see an option for specifying the Activity to InventoryItem relationship.

How do you create a Saved Search to get Files associated with InventoryItems?

Thank you!

I've tried accessing Files via PHPToolkit, but they aren't available. I'm trying to create a Saved Search to get them, but struggling to find the correct search criteria to associate InventoryItems, Activities and Files.